# Having trouble setting an event listener that invokes a function after checking if a targeted element is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

- I have an element in angular that is a custom directive.
- Attached to the element tag is a tabindex value of -1
- Attached to the element tag is an id 'myID'

  ```
   <myCustomDirective id="myID" tabindex="-1"></myCustomDirective>
  ```

I want to create an event listener that checks whether or not the element has focus. When it evaluates to true, for simplicity it'll just invoke a console log.

I have tried the following:

```
if ($("#myID").is(":focus")) {...}
```

But nothing happens

I have also tried

```
$(document.activeElement)
```

But it evaluates to true when ANY element has focus, not just the specific element i'm targetting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `focus` event to determine when an element has focus and the `blur` event to determine when the element loses focus.

Angular provides the [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) directives. If the event listener you're modifying is for a separate event, then use these directives to update some internal state (Angular's `$cacheFactory` can be useful) and check that state from the listener you are modifying.

Comment: Thanks, but Im looking to trigger a keydown event on an already focused element. Not looking to set up ng -focus/blur

Comment: Ok. Have you tried comparing the value returned from `document.activeElement` with the target element? It sounds like you've checked its truthiness but not it's value.

Comment: Not sure how to write that

Comment: For example you could compare the ID of the activeElement: `if ( document.activeElement.id == "myID" ) { ... }`. More details on document.activeElement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement